# Expected Identifier error in if statement

Tags: objective-c

I am trying to create a class similar to the built in `NSDictionary` class, but I want to add some extra functionality and make it easier to use.  In the .m file I have the following piece of code:

```
-(void)newEntryWithKey:(NSString *)theKey andValue:(NSString *)theValue{
    if (![theKey isEqual:@""]) && (![theValue isEqual:@""]){
        [self.keys addObject:theKey];
        [self.values addObject:theValue];
        self.upperBound++;
    }else{
        return
    }
}
```

It gives me an "Expected Identifier" error at the start of the second portion of the if statement after the "&&".  Would someone be able to help me with this?

EDIT: The original problem is fixed but now there is a new error at the end of the if statement.

```
-(void)newEntryWithKey:(NSString *)theKey andValue:(NSString *)theValue{
    if (theKey.length && theValue.length) {
        [self.keys addObject:theKey];
        [self.values addObject:theValue];
        self.upperBound++;
    }else{
        return
    } //<-- error here "Expected expression"
}
```

Comment: Missing `)`... asked not even a single time.

Comment: This question should be closed because it is predicated on a typo and will have no utility for future readers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (![theKey isEqual:@""] && ![theValue isEqual:@""]) {
```

Though a better check for non-empty strings would be:

```
if (theKey.length && theValue.length) {
```

Your original `if` statement will give incorrect results if either `theKey` or `theValue` is `nil`. My 2nd option works in either case.

Update:

The problem with the updated code is the missing `;` after the `return` statement.

Comment: That's a much better solution thanks.  I still have an error in my code however at the end of the if statement where it gives me an "expected expression" error at the final bracket.  Any ideas?

Comment: Without seeing the exact code it's hard to know. Update your question by adding exactly what you have now. Copy and paste the actual code into your question (do not put the code in a comment).

Comment: No, you keep the original part of the question intact. Add the updated  code as an additional update. Otherwise these two answers don't appear to make sense.

Comment: BTW - your new problem is simple - you forget the `;` after the `return`.

Comment: Ok i fixed it so the original question is there.  And now I feel like an idiot for such a dumb mistake.  I'm just used to not needing them.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Usually after if you should have one condition in parentheses. You're missing parentheses.

Comment: Ok thanks, I didn't realize they had to be grouped together as one expression.  Now i have an error at the closing bracket at the end of the if statement after "return" It says "expected expression."